# SIPp test for voip software

Tags: testing, memory, performance-testing

I have a VOIP software and I want to test it with sipp, is there a way to test memory leak with SIPp? for example writing some scenario and find the report on log?

I 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SIPp is a SIP traffic generator, it does not test memory leak by itself, but it can be used in conjuction with memory leak analysis tool.

Depending on the language you used for your VOIP software, different tools can be used for this purpose.

For example, if your software is written in C/C++, you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

This is how you run your program using valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2
```

Start your program with valgrind and then use SIPp to interact with your program and instruments your program